# Table 'xxxx.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist when connecting to AWS

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am using ASP.NET Web API Core 2.0 w/ EntityFramework to connect to an AWS MariaDB instance.

I also have a local MariaDB instance with the EXACT same schema.

When I run web API with local connection everything works fine.

I get Table 'xxxxx.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist when connecting to AWS. (xxxxx is the database name)

I even add the following to the ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
          : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("aspnetusers");
        builder.Entity<Profile>().ToTable("profiles");
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Note api call to profile works fine.

How can this be set up so EntityFramework doesn't look for 'xxxxx.table' but just the 'table'? Also recognizes 'aspnetusers'

```
 services
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
            .AddUnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

EDIT:

Connection String format for local vs aws

### local:

Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=xxxxxxx;Database=CoolAppDB

### aws:

Server=coolappdb.1234564798.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=3306;User Id=username;Password=xxxxxxx;Database=coolappdb

Comment: Maybe the answer lies in a difference in connection strings? One has the DB configured, and the other does not?

Comment: @H.Lowette added connection string formats for both local and aws

Comment: Is there a _VersionHistory table in both? Or is there a difference?

Comment: both are the same... used HeidiSQL tool to deploy the schema from local to aws